# Wordpress. Как передать данные полученные в Ajax (admin-ajax.php) в свой тег формы (шорткод) contactForms7?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Я использую Ajax в wordpress для передачи списка запчастей, а полученные данные хочу передать в форму contactForms7.

Уже настроил Ajax в wordpress по этой инструкции - https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html
и создал свой тег формы (шорткод) в форму cf7, как это было написано здесь (работает нормально) - https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/contact-form-7/sozdanie-tegov-formy#dobavlenie-tega-formy-shortkoda-v-contact-form-7-variant-2

А вот связать получаемые данные в AJAX c этим тегом формы (шорткодом) для вставки в форму cf7 не удается.

Вот ссылка на мой проект [web4hotel.ru/vellift](http://web4hotel.ru/vellift/)

Не могу понять, то ли мне нужно связывать хуки и передавать данные через параметры, то ли использовать глобальную переменную для передачи данных из одной функции в другую?

PHP почти не знаю, да и вообще новичок.

Пробовал использовать global - не вышло.
Пробовал запускать хуки из функции Ajax - не срабатывает шорткод в contactForms7.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться как перенести полученный список запчастей через Ajax в форму contactForms7. Уже несколько дней не могу решить.

[image: скриншот]

```php
//global $result;

/* AJAX из React*/
function react_callback() {
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $data = $data->arrObj;


  foreach($data as $obj){
      $result .= "$obj->id : $obj->winch : $obj->name : $obj->amount шт.; \n<br/>";
  };
    print_r($result);

    wp_die();

    //return apply_filters('wpcf7_form_elements', $result );
}
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_react', 'react_callback' );
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_react', 'react_callback' );

/* Добавление тега формы (шорткода) в Contact Form 7 (в шаблон письма) */
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'do_shortcode');

function my_shortcod_cf7_func() {
   return "Список деталей:  \n<br/>". $result;
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcod_cf7', 'my_shortcod_cf7_func');
```

Comment: Можете добавить свой [тег](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/contact-form-7/sozdanie-tegov-formy#dobavlenie-tega-formy-shortkoda-v-contact-form-7-variant-1) в форму и в нем выводить свой шаблон с нужными значениями.

Comment: @Алексей, это я как раз и делаю, именно по той инструкции что Вы указали. Спасибо, за участие. Может у Вас  будут идеи как передать данные полученные в Ajax (admin-ajax.php) в свой тег формы (шорткод) contactForms7?
Мне кажется должно быть просто, но из-за отсутствия опыта я погрузился во Мрак и чешу затылок через колено)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насчёт `$global`. Строка `$global $result;` должна присутствовать как в `react_callback()`, так и в `my_shortcod_cf7_func()`. А у вас в `my_shortcod_cf7_func()` `$result` локальная переменная, равна null. Но это не поможет.

Во вкладке response браузера вы видите выдачу из `react_callback()`. Страница не работает так, как вам хочется, в силу непонимания процессов клиент-серверного взаимодействия.

Страница формируется php. В этот момент работает CF7, создаёт форму, использует хуки. Вы своей функцией передаёте туда $result = null. `react_callback()` не вызывается, процесс php завершает работу и отправляет сформированную страницу в браузер. В форме имеем то, что на картинке.

При срабатывании ajax, в свою очередь, не вызывается функция `my_shortcod_cf7_func()`. Данные, сформированные в `react_callback()`, уходят назад в браузер, вы видите их во вкладке response, и на этом всё.

Вам нужно выбранные пользователем запчасти не через ajax отправлять, а просто через JS записывать в hidden (или не hidden) input формы CF7. Этот input должен быть прописан в форме в админке. При отправке формы всё содержимое уйдёт в письме.

Comment: А что нужно, что бы передать данные (список запчастей) в шаблон письма CF7?

Comment: Я вам в ответе написал, что нужно. Иметь input в форме, в него поместить кодом js выбранные пользователем запчасти.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.